# C# regex - not getting outer group

Tags: c#, regex

I am using the following Regular expression for finding the groups

```
string pattern = @"(?<member>(?>\w+))\((?:(?<parameter>(?:(?>[^,()""']+)|""(?>[^\\""]+|\\"")*""|@""(?>[^""]+|"""")*""|'(?:[^']|\\')*'|\((?:(?<nest>\()|(?<-nest>\))|(?>[^()]+))*(?(nest)(?!))\))+)\s*(?(?=,),\s*|(?=\))))+\)";
```

from the expression like

```
string Exp = "GetValue(GetValue(GetValue(1 + 2) * GetValue(3 * 4)) / GetValue(GetValue(5 * 6) / 7) / 8)";
```

I am getting the below groups :

a) GetValue(GetValue(1 + 2) * GetValue(3 * 4))

b) GetValue(GetValue(5 * 6) / 7)

I am getting all the groups but the outer group (**GetValue(.... / 8)**) is not getting ???

What could be the problem in the pattern ??

Comment: I tried creating a regexr, but it matches nothing at all: http://regexr.com?2voqv

Comment: Can you explain the desired result a little further? Specifically, what would you expect to be captured in each group: member, parameter, nest, -nest.

Answer (score 0):

My best help for you is to download and use this RegexDesigner

http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a complicated RegEx, it would be good to have and actual example for your search string. I have found in most of these cases you'll need to have a greedy RegEx match.

For example:

```
Non-Greedy:
"a.+?b":

Greedy:
"a.*b":
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have the following matches, it is not possible with regular expressions, alone:

1. GetValue(GetValue(GetValue(1 + 2) * GetValue(3 * 4)) / GetValue(GetValue(5 * 6) / 7) / 8)
2. GetValue(GetValue(1 + 2) * GetValue(3 * 4))
3. GetValue(1 + 2)
4. GetValue(3 * 4)
5. GetValue(GetValue(5 * 6) / 7) / 8)
6. GetValue(5 * 6) / 7)

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) for why. You could, however, use recursion to get the matches within your match, like (grossly untested pseudocode):

```
private List<string> getEmAll(string search)
{
    var matches = (new Regex(@"Your Expression Here")).Match(search);
    var ret = new List<string>();
    while (matches.Success)
    {
        ret.Add(matches.Value);
        ret.AddRange(getEmAll(matches.Value));
        matches = matches.NextMatch();
    }
    return ret;
}

...

getEmAll("GetValue(GetValue(GetValue(1 + 2) * GetValue(3 * 4)) / GetValue(GetValue(5 * 6) / 7) / 8)");
```

If you were wanting to separate out the matches further into matching groups, it would be slightly more complicated - but you get the gist.